# Remove trailing and first space from sku

Tags: magento2, database, sku, patch-data

I have Magento 2.2.2. Some SKU products contain a trailing space. How to using data patch or MySQL database query which will remove all leading and trailing spaces from SKU products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_entity` SET `sku`=TRIM(`sku`)
```